# Templates Objects and Primitives

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have the following class template which will accept both primitives and object. However like this I can only print primitives. How can I make it function using both primitives and objects? Thanks

```
template<class T>

    class A
    {

        private:
            vector <T> l;
        public:

            void print() const
            {
                for (int i=0;i<.size();i++)
                {
                    cout<<l[i]<<endl; //error here
                }

            } 
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you can print primitives is that `<iostream>` provides overloads for `operator<<` for them.

To let your template print your classes in the same way, you need to define your own implementation of the operator:

```
// This implementation puts operator << outside your class.
// Mark it "friend" in MyClass if it needs access to private members of MyClass.
ostream& operator<<(ostream& ostr, const MyClass& myClass) {
    // Do the printing based on the members of your class
    ostr << myClass.member1 << ":" << myClass.member2;
    return ostr;
}
```

The compiler will detect this operator during template expansion, and use it for printing when you do this:

```
cout<<l[i]<<endl;
```

You can put `operator<<` inside your class as well:

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream &os) {
    ostr << member1 << ":" << member2;
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error too many parameters. Am I missing something? Thankyou for your help

Comment: @fbdg Where do you see the error? Here is a [link to a demo of your code with the fix running on ideone](http://ideone.com/KjghLo).

Comment: I am writing this code in my object to overload the << 'ostream& TestClass:: operator<<(ostream& ostr, const TestClass &str)//error
{
    ostr << str.m_nproperty;
    return ostr;
}' And Im getting an error where I indicated above: binary 'operator <<' has too many parameters

Comment: Make the function as a friend function of the class.

Comment: @fbdg You can write `operator<<` inside your class. See edit for details.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that here, you want to print an object instead of a variable belonging to a fundamental datatype.

For such cases, you can look at operator overloading in C++(more specifically overloading insertion operator).

For more information about overloading the insertion operator for an object, you can visit this URL

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z2f6c2k.aspx

Given below is an example about how to go about it

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Datatype& dt) 
{
os << dt.a <<" " << dt.b;
return os;
}
```

Here Datatype is the name of the class and a and b are two private members of a and b which will be printed when you try to print the object.

However, to overload using this technique, do not forget to make this function as a friend function of the class(as given below) as the function requires access the to private members of the class.

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Datatype& dt);
```